# How to extract a part of a line that is between two specific strings via a batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, string-manipulation, text-manipulation

I am trying to extract strings which are between `testid=` and `]`.

Input text file

```
SEVERE  TEST 11/18/2019 8:00:41 AM  Could not find INPUT with [testid=2345]
SEVERE  TEST 11/18/2019 5:02:11 AM  Could not find INPUT with [testid=12345678]
```

Expected output

```
2345
12345678
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide answers to [well-asked questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). A part of asking a good question is doing some research before you ask, and letting us know what you already tried. Please update your question so that it shows that you put in some effort before posting your question here.

Comment: Other than the date and time, will each line of the input text file always read the same as above or does the text also change? my point being, you could scan each line until you hit the = sign, then capture the numbers until you hit the ] sign. Another method might be to start with the last character ] and back up until you hit the = sign.

Comment: You could do this quite easily with vb script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`findstr /I /C:"8:00:41" text.txt`) do (
set string=%%F
)
set string=%string:~68%
set string=%string:~,-1%
echo %string%
for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`findstr /I /C:"5:02:11" text.txt`) do (
set string2=%%F
)
set string2=%string2:~68%
set string2=%string2:~,-1%
echo %string2%
pause
```

The output you'll get is,

```
2345
12345678
Press any key to continue...
```

If you want to get rid of that last bit, replace the

```
pause
```

at the end, with a

```
pause > nul
```

and the output you'll get is

```
2345
12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a batch file using Regex in vbscript :

```bat
@echo off
Title Extract Data between string and char from a text file using RegExp
Set "InputFile=Test.txt"
Set "OutputFile=OutputFile.txt"
Call :ExtractData "%InputFile%" "%OutputFile%"
If Exist %OutputFile% Start "" %OutputFile%
Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:ExtractData <InputFile> <OutputFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Extract("%~1"^)
    echo Function Extract(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern,strResult,oRegExp,Match,colMatches 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "\[testid=(.+)\]"
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True
    echo oRegExp.Multiline = True
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo set colMatches = oRegExp.Execute(Data^)
    echo For Each Match in colMatches
    echo    strResult = strResult ^& Match.SubMatches(0^) ^& vbcrlf
    echo Next
    echo Extract = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output file is like this :

```
2345
12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

This batch file with extract the text between (the first) `testid=`
(if any) on each line and the (first) subsequent `]` (if any),
regardless of where in the line they appear,
with one exception that I was able to identify (see bottom of answer):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%L in (input.txt) do (
    set line=%%L
    set right1=!line:*testid=!
    if not !line! == !right1! (
        set left=!right1:~0,1!
        if "!left!" == "=" (
            set right2=!right1:~1!
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=]" %%W in ("!right2!") do (
                if not %%W == !right2! (
                    echo.%%W
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` lets you work intelligently
  with variables in loops.
- `for /f "tokens=*" %%L in (input.txt)` reads `input.txt` a line at a time
  and puts each line into index variable `%%L`.
- `set line=%%L` copies the text into a regular variable,
  which is easier to manipulate.
- `set right1=!line:*testid=!`
  uses the `% var : str1 = str2 %` syntax
  for doing a string substitution in a variable expansion
  (spaces are added for clarity).

  - Using `!` instead of `%` because of delayed expansion.
  - *`var`* is `line`, obviously.
  - *`str1`* is `*testid`. 
    The `*` is a wildcard (pattern matching symbol), so this matches
    everything up through the first occurrence of `testid` in `line`. 
    Note that, while we would like *`str1`* to be `*testid=`,
    but, unfortunately, it’s impossible for *`str1`* to contain `=`,
    because `=` is the delimiter between *`str1`* and *`str2`*.
  - *`str2`* is null.

  So this replaces everything
  up through the first occurrence of `testid` in `line` with null,
  and returns everything after `testid`.
- If the line doesn’t contain `testid`,
  the above returns the entire `line`, unchanged. 
  So, if `line` equals `right1`, there was no `testid` in the line. 
  If they are different, proceed to analyze this line.
- `set left=!right1:~0,1!` extracts the first (leftmost) character
  from `right1`.
- `if "!left!" == "="`, the first character after `testid` is `=`,
  so we have found `testid=` and we want to continue analyzing the line.
- `set right2=!right1:~1!` sets `right2` to be all of `right1`
  except for the first character; i.e., after the `=`.
- `for /f "tokens=1 delims=]" %%W in ("!right2!")` breaks `right2` apart
  at the first `]`, putting the text before `]` into `%%W`.
- If `%%W == !right2!`, there was no `]` in the line.
- If we found `testid=` and `]`, then `%%W` is the text between them.
  You should probably assign it to a regular variable.

Disclosure: given the line

```
[testid=a] and [testid=b]
```

this batch file will find `a` only; it will not find `b`. 
Given the line

```
[testid<c] and [testid=d]
```

the batch file will not find anything; the first `testid` throws it off.